# Two override functions of the same pure-virtual function with different parameters?

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I have an abstract class `A` and a pure-virtual function `toDoOrNotToDo` in it. I have two subclasses, `A1` and `A2`, such that `A1` needs the `const int x` parameter of `toDoOrNotToDo` to do its job, and `A2` doesn't need that parameter to do it's job.

But if I write

```
class A2 : public A {
public:
    int toDoOrNotToDo() const override;
};
```

It will obviously complain:

> ‘int A2::toDoOrNotToDo() const’ marked override, but does not override

I can just write:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual int toDoOrNotToDo(const int x) const = 0;
    virtual ~A();
};

class A1 : public A {
public:
    int toDoOrNotToDo(const int) const override;
};

class A2 : public A {
public:
    int toDoOrNotToDo(const int) const override;
};
```

But then in `A2::toDoOrNotToDo` I have a parameter that I don't need.

How can I improve the design?

Comment: You could use a defaulted parameter instead. As long those functions do not have the same signature, they'll never match in virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decide on the interface first. If the `int` parameter is not supposed to be needed for the function, then an implementation cannot require it without violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

If it is supposed to be needed, just put it into the interface class. As long as the parameter is documented as "may not affect the result," all is well.

However, the whole situtation looks like a bad design to me—maybe the abstraction is not really valid and you're using the wrong tool for the job?